# How to use a service-name as address to fetch dynamic route in next.js

Tags: docker, kubernetes, next.js

I need to have a kubernetes cluster with a NextJS front-end and one service where I would make requests from the front-end to the other service in the cluster using fetch.

The problem is, I can't build the docker image to use in the kubernetes deployment because fetch fails in buildtime since it can't find an address 'service-name'.

For example:

```js
// ../[categoria]/page.js

export async function getListaProdutos() {
    const produtos = await fetch(`http://produtos-service:80/api/produtos`).then((res) => res.json())

    return produtos
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const produtos = await getListaProdutos()

    return produtos.map((produto) => ({
        categoria: produto.categoria,
    }))
}
```

```
- info Collecting page data ...TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11600:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND produtos-service
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26)
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'produtos-service'
  }
}

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /cardapio/[categoria]
    at /home/wallysf/Área de trabalho/Sorveteria/frontend/sorveteria/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1158:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

From what I've understood of the nextjs documentation, if I deleted generateStaticParams() it should only be ran at runtime, but that isn't working for me.

I've tried searching but didn't find anything that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to build the static version of multiple pages with data retrieved from service at build time. If that is correct and intentional, then you need to make your service responsible to send data accessible to host that is building the docker container.

Alternatively, if you do not want to generate these pages during build time (ahead of time), you can opt into enforcing the route segment (page) to be fully dynamic so it is prevented to be built at build time and instead the data is fetched at runtime of the request execution. Check Route Segment Config in Next.js with App Router - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config.

`export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` at the top of page.js will skip the fetch at building and instead move it to runtime.

Comment: Tried adding this const, as well as 'dynamicParams = true' and 'revalidate = 0', but didn't work :(
Any other way to force it to go to runtime? That's what I need

Comment: It actually worked. I just had to delete (or comment) the generateStaticParams() function, which makes sense since I don't want to be static anymore. Thanks